# Wait until DispatchWorkItem is done

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have `DispatchWorkItem` that fetch some info and I have a button that displays the info. The worker looks like this:

```
worker = DispatchWorkItem {
    let info = getInfo()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setInfo(info)
    }
}
```

on `viewDidLoad` I add the worker to the global queue

```
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35, execute: worker!)
```

When the user clicks on the button I need the execution to be blocked until the worker has finished execution.

```
@IBAction func readInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // WAIT UNTIL THE WORKER HAS FINISHED EXECUTION
    ...
```

I managed to do so by having the worker looking like this:

```
worker = DispatchWorkItem {
    let info = getInfo()
    self.setInfo(info)
}
```

and by checking if the info was set every 200 ms after the user clicks on the button:

```
@IBAction func readInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    while(info == nil){
        usleep(2000)
    }
    ...
```

However I want all the variables to be accessible only by the main thread.

Comment: Don't *wait*, notify

Comment: @vadian can you please elaborate

Comment: Use an asynchronous pattern to notify when the task has finished rather than expensive synchronous polling. `while(info == nil){ usleep(2000)}` is horrendous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't clearly understand what you wanted, but it's inappropriate to use such a thing as `usleep(2000)`.

So, there is a possible solution, but it's general and you probably need to modify it for your needs.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
var info: Info?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.35) { [weak self] in
        self?.getInfo()
    }
}

func getInfo() {
    group.enter()
    asyncFunc()

    group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
        self?.setInfo(self?.info)
    }
}

func asyncFunc() {
    ..... { [weak self] info in
        self?.info = info
        self?.group.leave()
    }
}
```

If you want to disable user interaction while something is loading, it's better to show progressive loader, but not just freeze the application. In case with the loader, users will understand, that the app isn't frozen.

There is an example of using DispatchWorkItem with DispatchGroup:

```
let dispatchWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem{
    print("work item start")
    sleep(1)
    print("work item end")
}

let dg = DispatchGroup()
//submiy work items to the group
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "custom dq")
dispatchQueue.async(group: dg) {
    print("block start")
    sleep(2)
    print("block end")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async(group: dg, execute: dispatchWorkItem)
//print message when all blocks in the group finish
dg.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
    print("dispatch group over")
}
```

[Code from here](https://medium.com/@yostane/swift-sweet-bits-the-dispatch-framework-ios-10-e34451d59a86)

Comment: I am using a `DispatchWorkItem` because there are some cases where I need to cancel the worker. How can I do that using a DispathWorkItem?

Comment: You can still use 'DispatchWorkItem' instead of closures. But the main point here is using dispatch group to notify when your work finished instead of 'usleep'

Comment: I updated my answer. It may help you understand how to use work items with groups.

Comment: Dispatch framework is powerful enough to fulfill all your needs, just spend some time to understand which approaches you can use.